# trying to write COPIED data in a text file in python

Tags: python, winapi, copy-paste

I have copied the data from a file, and I am trying to paste it to file guru99.txt, but it is not writing to the file. Below is the piece of code. Can anyone please help me, I want to paste the copied data in txt file which I have opened?

```
import win32api
import win32com.client
import pyautogui
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
win32api.Sleep(5000)
pyautogui.moveTo(17, 213) #moving cursor to a location on software to select data
win32api.Sleep(2000)
pyautogui.click()   #selecting data
win32api.Sleep(2000)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c') #copying data
win32api.Sleep(2000)
file_text= open("guru99.txt","w+") #making new txt file to paste copied data
file_text.write(pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')) #pasting data using write fn, which is giving error
win32api.Sleep(2000)
file_text.close()
```

Comment: Are those win32api.Sleep(2000) the same as os.sleep(2000)? Because that means your program is sleeping for 2000 seconds each time that is called.

Comment: Please post the contents of WScript.shell too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a really unpythonic way of doing what you want to do. Also, note that when you use `open(filename)`, you are not physically opening the file. You are just reading its contents to the memory. So from pyautogui's point of view, the file is not open. Hence *Ctrl+V* won't work.

Since you were able to copy the data into clipboard, the pasting part is simple.

Type this in command prompt:

```
pip install pyperclip
```

After you are able to execute "ctrl+c" in your script:

```
import pyperclip
s = pyperclip.paste() 
with open('new.txt','w') as g:
   g.write(s)
```

Comment: the author of question seems like, trying to deal with clipboard.

Comment: @Haranadh Not really, as he is invoking the 'ctrl+c' which implies that the data is not present in the clipboard to begin with.

Comment: cool :), I agree, he is trying to automate copy paste in some script. may not be doing actual copy file... in case of he is copying from file to file. I up-vote  your answer.

Comment: yea, I'm waiting for his comment to update my answer as he didn't give sufficient information to begin with.

Comment: Thank You.
I am not trying to copy and paste data from one file to another.
I have a software wherein I have to select the data and paste it in a text file for analysis.
You can see move cursor command and then a click command (which selects the data),
then I copied the data using CNTRL + C, but I am facing challenge to paste it in a text file.
If I manually paste it works, but how do I code to paste that COPIED piece in a text file?
Please help

Comment: Perfect !! This is what I was looking for. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Hi, I am trying to assign dynamic name to the text file like : new1.txt, new2.txt every time I call the function. But it is giving error. If anyone can help me, I have posted it on :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033328/facing-issue-while-providing-dynamic-name-to-file-in-python-through-a-function?noredirect=1#comment77040153_45033328