# Facing issue while providing dynamic name to file in python through a function

Tags: python

the line : with open('new%s.txt' % intg ,'a') as g : is giving error in below code.
Every time I call the function "Repeat", it should create file with name new1.txt, new2.txt and so on. 
But it is giving error : "name 'intg' is not defined"
I want dynamic name for screenshot file and txt file, to prevent overwriting of file. 
The code is for selecting data from a software, copying it, and pasting it in new file each time.
Please help:

```
import win32api
import win32com.client
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
win32api.Sleep(5000)

def repeat( intg ):
    import pyautogui
    pyautogui.moveTo(17, 213)
    win32api.Sleep(2000)
    pyautogui.screenshot('%s.png' % intg)
    pyautogui.click()
    win32api.Sleep(2000)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    s = pyperclip.paste() 
    win32api.Sleep(2000)
    with open('new%s.txt' % intg ,'a') as g:
        g.write(s)
    print("done")

repeat( intg = 1 )
repeat( intg = 2 )

win32api.Sleep(5000)
print ("done")
```

Comment: Please fix your indentations

Comment: please avoid import inside a function. Also, I'm assuming your using python3 regarding to the parenthesis when you call print; if so, may you please tag it so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can concatenate integer and strings doing so:

```
with open('new' + str(intg) + '.txt','a') as g:
```

or doing so:

```
with open('new{0}.txt'.format(intg),'a') as g:
```

Comment: Had tried this, it doesn't work. Gives same error : name 'intg' is not defined

Comment: is your code indented the way I edited it ?
btw, using % is not wrong but is deprecated.

Comment: Hi, It worked now. My indentations were incorrect. Thank u :)